# CoreImage transition between NSViews

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, transition, core-image

One year at WWDC apple showed using CoreImage transitions to switch between two NSViews. It was a simple example where changing tabs changed the view with a swirl animation or something like that. The presenter joked never to actually do something like this in a real app. Does anyone remember that sample and remember what it was called or have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducer has an `AnimatingTabView` that uses CIFilters to animate switching between tabViews.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Reducer/Introduction/Intro.html